# Multiple jobs not found in "Looking for a job?" section

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I've noticed multiple dead links in this section over the past few days. Is there a mechanism in place to no longer show these when a job has been removed or expired?

[image: Looking for a job?]

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/72517/senior-ui-ux-client-side-developer-catalytic-data-science?a=ojQiOoN6s0O

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/72248/staff-it-business-system-analyst-arris?a=oefw59pK7Un

Comment: Confirmed - 2 of 4 currently listed for me are not found: [this one](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/69522/lead-java-developer-polaris-industries?a=njzUXlTuP2q) as well as [this one](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/72418/salesforce-web-developer-university-of-minnesota?a=ohMFRorSWKT)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was indeed a problem with job listings synchronization, leading to some expired jobs being mistakenly advertised.

The issue has been identified and fixed, there shouldn't be any dead link anymore.

Thank you for your report!

Comment: Works as expected now. Awesome quick response!

Comment: Cheers, so guess it can be tagged [tag:status-completed] now? :)