# Careers "looking for a job" ad leads to "Not Found" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

It looks like the Careers ad is broken again.

The "Looking for a job" and "Jobs near you" ads on Stack Overflow just lead to a blank white page with the words "Not Found".

[The blank page in question](http://clc.stackoverflow.com/j/ct/undefined?an=Y6x09DxX8v-iR9l8RQZGRgaW7Q0MDAf-zrDb_GeuPTMrMwMjA6MNkGBmZmBgsFsEk9trzwSRkwMSJyUY4VqgwilA4qAvQjULQjULI9AkFlYgEbpMdpPh673LJYQB&ca=undefined&utm=%26utm_source%3Dstackoverflow.com%26utm_medium%3Dad%26utm_campaign%3Djobs-large-sidebar-blue-looking)

Related: [Multiple jobs not found in "Looking for a job?" section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244592/multiple-jobs-not-found-in-looking-for-a-job-section)

Comment: Looking into it right now, will get back later today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, this was my fault.

We recently changed how we track analytics for those sidebar job ads, and part of that is a bit of script that attaches an event handler to the `<a>` tags in those job listings. The selector I used for those event handlers was too broad, and the header and footer links were included when they shouldn't have been.

I've pushed a fix and it should be rolling out to production shortly.